# draw shape on input gives unexpected result how to fix?

Tags: processing, shapes, dynamically-generated

I want to draw a shape based on the input of a slider. see the code below:

```java
import controlP5.*;
ControlP5 cp5;

int people = 5;
int DMamt = 0;
int peoplehis;
Slider abc;

PShape vorm;

void setup() {
   cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
   size(displayWidth, displayHeight);

   cp5.addSlider("people")
     .setPosition(10,10)
     .setWidth(400)
     .setRange(0,20)
     .setValue(0)
     .setNumberOfTickMarks(20)
     .setSliderMode(Slider.FIX)
   ;  

   cp5.addSlider("DMamt")
     .setPosition(450,10)
     .setWidth(400)
     .setRange(0,255) 
     .setValue(0)
     .setNumberOfTickMarks(5)
     .setSliderMode(Slider.FIX)
  ;  

  vorm = createShape();
  frameRate(10);
}


void draw(){

  if(peoplehis != people){
     vorm.beginShape();
     vorm.fill(DMamt);
     for(int i = 0; i <= people; i++){
        vorm.vertex(random(500), random(500));
     }
     endShape();
  }
  peoplehis = people;

  shape(vorm, 100,100); 
}
```

the first time i set the slider value i get a shape with the desired amount of points. but when i change the slider value after the first time the value of the slider get added to the points that are already drawn. but i want a new shape. the old shape should be gone. see below for a example:

first value of slider = 5
this gives me a shape with 5 points (GREAT);

second value of silder = 12
this gives me a shape with 17 points (NOT GREAT)
i want 12 points instead of 17.

how do i do this?? i am not very experienced with code :(

Comment: In the future, please try to provide a [mcve]. Your question doesn't have anything to do with ControlP5, so that code is just extra. Try to hardcode as much as possible, that way it's easier for us to run your code.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: yeah in the end i went with a total different approach and that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

A Processing `PShape` can consist of multiple shapes, which you can add by calling the `beginShape()`, `vertex()`, and `endShape()` functions multiple times.

If you just want to recreate a new shape instead of adding multiple shapes, then call the `createShape()` function again to start over with a new `PShape` instance. Also, make sure you clear out previous frames by calling the `background()` function.

Here is a simple example:

```java
PShape shape;

void setup() {

   size(500, 500);

  shape = createShape();
  frameRate(60);
}

void mousePressed(){
  shape = createShape();
  shape.beginShape();
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    shape.vertex(random(width), random(height));
  }
  shape.endShape();
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  shape(shape, 0,0); 
}
```